# adoquery1: parameter 'firstname' not found

Tags: delphi, parameters

I am new to Delphi. I get this error every time I run things:

> adoquery1: parameter 'firstname' not found

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

ADOQuery1.Close;

ADOQuery1.sql.Clear;

ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:=Memo1.Text; 
  //( in memo  I wrote this codes "insert into adlar (firstname) values(:edit1)")


ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('firstname').Value:=Edit1.Text;

ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:=Memo1.Text; //( in memo I wrote this codes "insert into adlar (firstname) values(:edit1)")

Well, if that's what is in `Memo1.Text`, the SQL doesn't contain a parameter named "firstname", it has a parameter named "edit1" instead, so unless you already have a persistent parameter (created in the IDE using the Object Inspector) with that name, you will get that error.

Try it with `Memo1.Text` containing:

```
insert into adlar (firstname) values(:firstname)
```

Or else change the name you are passing to `ParamByName()`:

```
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('edit1').Value:=Edit1.Text;
```